# How to capture screenshots with Selenium when running tests on a Jenkins agent

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, pytest

Right now I'm using pytest and selenium to run tests on Jenkins. When I run the code below locally it creates a screenshot after each test, which is working great.

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    if 'selenium' not in item.fixturenames or 'selenium' not in item.funcargs:
        return

    driver = item.funcargs['selenium']
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call' or report.when == "setup":
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url(driver.current_url, name = "Go To URL Tested"))
        if not report.skipped:
            report_directory = os.path.dirname(item.config.option.htmlpath)
            file_name = f"{item.originalname}.png"
            screenshot_was_saved = driver.get_screenshot_as_file(f"{report_directory}\\{file_name}")
            if file_name:
                report.screenshot = html.a(html.img(src = file_name, onclick = "window.open(this.src)", align = "right", style = "max-height: 150px;"), href = "#")
        report.extra = extra
```

But when I run that same code in my build pipeline on Jenkins, the images don't get created. The value that is returned from the `get_screenshot_as_file` method is `False`. There are no exceptions being returned and the tests pass. The Jenkins agent has permission to write files because the directory where I'm dumping to HTML report gets created. The index.html for the report gets created as well. Everything is there except for the images.

Does anyone have experience with something like this? I even tried running the chrome driver in headless mode and that didn't make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your selenium code works without jenkins?

Comment: Yes it works outside of Jenkins fine. It also works fine when I RDP into the Jenkins server and run pytest in a PowerShell console.

Comment: Most probably an issue with headless mode.

Comment: Try to use `driver.save_screenshot()` or even create a dummy jenkins job that tries to capture the screen via a different lib, e.g `PIL.ImageGrab.grab()` or `pyautogui.screenshot()`, will you get the pic bits? if not, what is the error message produced?

Comment: @arjabbar are you running your tests on slave? This could be the issue from my experience

Comment: No the tests are running on master. And I'll try using those methods you talked about @hoefling and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    """
    Extends the PyTest Plugin to take and embed screenshots in html report, whenever test fails.
    :param item:
    """
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])

    if report.when == 'call':
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            report_directory = os.path.dirname(item.config.option.htmlpath)
            file_name = str(int(round(time.time() * 1000))) + ".png"
            # full_path = os.path.join("C:\Screenshots", file_name)
            full_path = os.path.join(report_directory, file_name)
            if item.funcargs.get('driver'):
                print(f"[INFO] screenshot: {full_path}")
                item.funcargs['driver'].get_screenshot_as_file(full_path)
                if file_name:
                    html = '<div><img src="%s" alt="screenshot" style="width:304px;height:228px;" ' \
                           'onclick="window.open(this.src)" align="right"/></div>' % file_name
                    extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
        report.extra = extra
```

Comment: It doesn't work : "driver" (and I try with "selenium") is unknow

Comment: it does work, you need to put in conftest.py (pytest)

Comment: ... this condition return False :

   if item.funcargs.get('driver'):

Comment: i have a fixture which yields a driver instance 

@pytest.fixture()
def driver(request):
.....